# Little light-green / yellow spots on my avocado plant leaf

Tags: plant-health, indoors, leaves, avocado

So, basically I have this avocado plant that I grew from a seed a year ago.
It is progressing really great. Planted in pot and staying indoors, located near direct afternoon sunlight.

I had this problem before, I guess, but then it happened only to one or two leaves.

Now my baby has more leaves and these dots on leaves are spreading rapidly.

I don't know what it is. Some leaves even got brown "burn" on their tips.

I water it with tap water, but I did that way from the start.
Maybe I've put too much fertilizer(s). Cos the last thing I remember is that I've put two fertilizer sticks in the pot. Had (stupid) idea that it can't do much harm.

This is something that just occured recently, so have in mind that this is early stage of the issue...

What do you recommend doing?

[image: Avocado leaf]

Comment: anything that shouldn't be there on the underside of the leaf? You may need a magnifying glass to see properly...

Comment: Similar ?  https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8633/what-is-happening-to-the-leaves-of-my-avocado

Comment: actually not. it seems just like on the other side. or just more transparent than it shoud be (bottom sid of leaf)

Comment: I tried to google it my problem. Is it possible my avocado got fungus possibly called anthracnose?

Comment: also no one mentioned it can be salt burn? how to know the difference?